# ASP.NET MVC SimpleMembership user credentials apparently disconnecting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Sorry if the question title seems a little vague - I can't think how to put it better.

Here's the deal: Pretty new to to MVC, using MVC 5 with VS2013.

I'm using Simple Membership with a custom user table and am pointing membership to my own data.  When I seed my database I create a user, and that seems fine - I can log in, change password, update details - all's good.

When I stop debugging and make a change to my code and start debugging again, then when I hit my account controller WebSecurity.CurrentUserID is -1, but WebSecurity.CurrentUserName is correct (from my own table).  If I call WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken() I get an exception saying that the user with the user name I'm specifying doesn't exist, even though the record is still in the table.  I can still reach controllers protected by [Authorize], so the cookie seems OK (I'm not closing the browser between builds).

However, if I log off I can't log back in again - WebSecurity.Login() fails.  It's as if the connection to my database table has broken, but if I call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() I get an exception saying I can't call it twice - not surprising as I haven't stopped the debug web server.

The only way I get back in is if I drop the database and reseed, but that's only good until I need to change some code.

Really don't know where to go from here - any suggestions?

Comment: In my Global.asax.cs i'm calling `if(!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient","People","PersonId","Email", true);` the true is "autoCreateTables": what value are you passing?

Comment: Similar, but I use a different overload and call it from AuthConfig.RegisterAuth():
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContextClass", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Answer (score 0):

The cookie remembers the UserName, not the UserId, so if you are getting UserId==-1 then the cookie might work but WebSecurity is not connecting to the database so something has gone wrong before then.

Put this in your _Layout.cshtml, and check the value of .Initialized...

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>CurrentUserId: @WebSecurity.CurrentUserId</li>
        <li>CurrentUserName: @WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</li>
        <li>WebSecurity.Initialized: @WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized</li>
        @foreach (var k in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            <li>Cookie: @k</li>
            if (k == ".ASPXAUTH")
            {
                var ticket = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[k].Value);
                var ticketString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticket);
                <li>FormsAuthenticationTicket: @ticketString</li>
            }
        }

    </ul>

</div>
```

Put this in HomeController.Index...

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName))
            {
                var userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);

                var connectionString =
                    "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=CloudMinder5;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
                var providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

                var cmd = (string.Format("select PersonId from People where Email='{0}'", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName));
                //do not let little Bobby drop table use this system!
                //http://xkcd.com/327/

                var db = WebMatrix.Data.Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName);
                var userId2 = db.QueryValue(cmd, null);
// **** put a breakpoint here. does userId2==userId ? ****
            }
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Does your connection string have "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" ? if not, add it. Maybe WebSecurity can't get a connection to the database.